Squares of sum of digits of numbers part 3
This is the third part of my first post about properties of sum of squares of a number. Anyone who is new may refer to the link below.
Squares of sum of digits of a number
Here is a quick summary:
Take a number then add up it digits and square the result. Repeat the process to the number obtained and keep doing so. I the end we will get either $1,81,169,256$.
This was proved in the first post.
Now suppose we do this to a number until we get $1,81,169,256$. The moment we get anyone number out of the $4$ we stop the sequence. What is the probability that the sequence ends in any one of $1,81,169,256$.

How are you choosing the starting number? You can't choose a natural number uniformly at random. You could do so through a distribution e.g. geometric.

Please [edit] your post to make it self-contained.  I can't tell what your question is.   Don't force us to click on links to understand what you are asking.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question.  Normally a question should end with "?"

What are your thoughts?  What is the motivation for why others might care about this question or the context in which it arose?

@D.W. here is the full story. Disclaimer: it may be boring..... In 2023 I qualified for the second stage of international mathematical olympiad in my country and there was a question in the exam to find all distinct numbers m and n such that square of sum of digits of m is equal to n and square of sum of digits of n equals m. The question in the link was a lemma I used during the proof but failed to prove it in exam and so got 0 for that question. But I tried to find answers on MSE and it was one of my popular posts. I was just thinking about other aspects in the problem that led to this.

The above was my motivation and why I care. As for others I don't think they would have any other reason to care except for the bounty or the fact that this is a wonderful amalgamation of probability and number theory.

@A.M. Probably they want to choose the starting number from a uniform distribution on ${1, \dots, n}$ and then take a limit of the resulting probabilities as $n \to \infty$, assuming the limit converges. That's my guess at least

Here's a partial answer, under the assumption that you want to take a uniform random starting number from $\{1, \dots, N\}$ and then look at the limiting behavior as $N \to \infty$.
Let $f(n)$ denote the first number from $\{1, 81, 169, 256\}$ that we land on starting at $n$. If $s(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$, then $s(n) \equiv n \pmod 9$. This is well-known and easy to show. Then $s(n)^2 \equiv n^2 \pmod 9$.
Let's look at numbers and their squares modulo $9$. I'll split them into three classes: $A = \{0, 3, 6\}$, $B = \{1, 8\}$, and $C = \{2, 4, 5, 7\}$. Every number in each class squares to another number in the same class. Therefore, if our starting number $n$ is in a certain class, then $f(n)$ is in the same class. If $n \in A \pmod 3$ then $f(n) = 81$, and if $n \in B \pmod 9$ then $f(n) = 1$. As $N \to \infty$, the probability that a uniform random $n$ falls into class $A$ approaches $1 / 3$. And similarly for class $B$ we get $2 / 9$.
Now, how is the remaining $4 / 9$ probability split between $169$ and $256$? This I can't answer. All numbers in class $C$ alternate between $4$ and $7$ modulo $9$, so I would have guessed that about half would land on $169 \equiv 7 \pmod 9$ and the other half on $256 \equiv 4 \pmod 9$. However, running a computer simulation seems to indicate that very large numbers are about twice as likely (or more) to land on $169$ than $256$.

I have performed a computer simulation that calculates the exact probabilities of ending at $\{0, 1, 81, 169, 256\}$ from a starting number in $\{0, 1, \dots, 10^d\}$ for $1 \leq d < 5000$.
Note that ending at $0$ is only possible if the starting number equals $0$, so this probability will vanish as $d \to \infty$.
I have plotted the result, which can be seen below.
In the plot, the value of $d$ is listed on the x-axis and the probability of ending at each of $\{0, 1, 81, 169, 256\}$ is listed on the y-axis.
Note that this answer does not answer the question, it is merely an interesting result, which did not fit in a comment.


Update: I improved my algorithm, which can now approximate (to unknown accuracy) the probabilities of ending at $\{0, 1, 81, 169, 256\}$ from a starting number in $\{0, 1, \dots, 10^{2^p}\}$ for $1 \leq p \leq 26$.
Listing the probability of ending at $169$ and $256$, respectively, for some $p$'s we get:
20: [0.3229072415185169, 0.1215372029259365]
21: [0.3525997163737325, 0.0918447280707314]
22: [0.3565506315236761, 0.0878938129207874]
23: [0.3553829797083236, 0.0890614647361787]
24: [0.3092395404207834, 0.1352049040237175]
25: [0.3217452008711443, 0.1226992435733908]
26: [0.3294311770014319, 0.1150132674431534]

which give lower probabilities of ending at $256$ than the values I computed before.
This may signify that as $p \to \infty$ we may have $0$ probability of ending at $256$, but that is just a guess.

This does give a verification of the result of user crb233 but does the probability of 169 or 256 approach any number?

@AarushSaharan, I don't know what number it approaches. I updated my answer, but I did not find an answer to that question (yet).

Maybe the probability just keeps oscillating like in your graph. Can we predict is behavior?

Does anyone notice that probability of 169 and 256 are reflections of each other in tthe graph. Why is this true?

@AarushSaharan, logically the sum of all the probabilities equals 1. The probability of ending at 0 quickly converges to 0. By crb233's answer we known that the probability of landing at 169 plus the probability of landing at 256 equals $4/9$. Both graphs are thus reflections around $2/9$, which is coincidentally the same as the probability of landing on 1.
